# implementing single sign on using LDAP

Tags: asp.net, ldap, single-sign-on

We want to develop application for customer which uses `LDAP` for authentication makes it use for single sign on `(SSO)` technique.We are very beginner about this topic.

What we think about `LDAP` upto now is(Correct me if i am wrong):

1. There is `LDAP server` somewhere which contains users and its
   associated role.
2. when user browse our web application it asks to enter username and
   password (which is actually credentials for `LDAP server`)
3. when `LDAP server` authenticates it sends a token to our web
   application ,we put that token in cookies and use this token to
   authenticate users for every web application with in our domain.
4. so using this technique we do not have to make additional modules
   for `user managemen`t.

what we are missing ?

Any idea will be appreciated/

Thanks in Advance